# Xcode - Create timeout for NSURL

Tags: mysql, ios, nsurl

I use `NSURL` to load some things from an MySQL Database. Sometimes this is very slow and the app stops running because the Database is not answering.
I thought I could make a timeout, so after e.g. 3 seconds, the app stops loading the `NSURL` and tries again or does something else like an `UIAlertView`.

Please help me!
Jannes

PS: I use this code to load these things from the Database:

```
-(void) loadSomething {
   NSError *error;
   NSString *urlString = @"http://someip/App/somefile.txt";
   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];

   @try {
      NSString *resultString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:url encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:&error];

   }
   @catch (NSException *exception) {

      NSLog(@"Error");

   }
```

Comment: Jannes have you considered downloading image async, and leaving the application responsible to UI?

Comment: As Smiless says, do this asynchronously. Never block the main thread. BTW, once you use `NSURLConnection` or `NSURLSession` or `AFNetworking` or whatever, you can also control the timeout interval, but because you're now doing it asynchronously, you won't really care that much about it and the default timeouts may be fine.

Comment: Is there any way in NSURLConnection, that it tries again on error or after a certain time without response?

Answer (score 0):

Your request is a `synchronous request` and this type of request freezes the ui, you should use an `asynchronous request` to prevent the freeze.
Here is a [tutorial](http://codewithchris.com/tutorial-how-to-use-ios-nsurlconnection-by-example) on request asynch / synch that should help you.

Otherwise perhaps think to use the framework " [AFNETWorking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) " it greatly simplifies the use of NSURLConnection and NSURLRequest

Comment: I already use asynchronous request. But my website hangs sometimes. So I need a timeout. So it repeats the NSURL after 3 seconds or so...